# Migrate Sybase Date to Oracle Date

Tags: oracle11g, sybase, sap-ase, dbmigrate

I am migrating my database from Sybase to oracle. I have generated insert statement from Sybase and trying to insert in Oracle database. I am getting error for date time.

In insert statement sybase date is in format "08/20/2007 09:41:00.000 AM"

And oracle is expecting date in format "14-NOV-15 06.22.28.000000000 PM".

Can any one please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You will need to convert the date either in the export statement or in the import statement.  Since you haven't given us any details, I can't give you an answer.

Comment: Can you please help to find how to convert base date "08/20/2007 09:41:00.000 AM" into oracle date format "14-NOV-15 06.22.28.000000000 PM" in either way.  I have write that statement in my insert statements.

Comment: I am not able to find what the format of this Sybase date "08/20/2007 09:41:00.000 AM"

Comment: Still not helping.  What version of Sybase are you exporting from? How did you create the insert statement?  How was the data exported from the Sybase DB?  Are you using any 3rd party tools to help? It appears that the format may be type 101, but without knowing more about the process, again we can't help you.  Details are needed, even if you don't think they are important.